# Searching a user by country city state district

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

spring and mysql I have tables in mysql **Country State,City, District and Lawyer** table. Now the user can search by providing the tag in UI scenarios are

1->User can search lawyer by district

2->User can search lawyer  by city

3-> USer can search lawyer  by State,

4->USer can search lawyer  by Country

5->User can search  lawyer by State, City and District

6->User can search lawyer by Only State and City

7 ->User can provide all four for more fined grained search

For Efficient and fast search what would the be the table relation with lawyer and all four table Country, State ,City and district

I have already made a table for Country,State, City and District with following relation ship
Country---one to many---------State--------on to many-- City------------on to many---------District

but now I want to establish relation with lawyer table so if some wants search lawyer with name or anything from above search criteria I would be able to give fast and optimize result by querying the table.

Should I create one more table containing lawyerid,stateId,countryId,cityid and districtId?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create five tables.

District with the primary key.

City with the primary key and the reference (foreign key) to the district.

State with the primary key and the reference (foreign key) to the city.

Country with the primary key and the reference (foreign key) to the state.

And a lawyer with the primary key and the references (foreign keys) to the country, state, city and district.

During the search you will create a simple and fast LEFT JOIN's:

```
SELECT lawyer.name, lawyer.data
FROM lawyer
LEFT JOIN country ON lawyer.country_id = country.id
WHERE country.name = "USA";
```

or for more compex queries:

```
SELECT lawyer.name, lawyer.data
FROM lawyer
LEFT JOIN ON state lawyer.state_id = state.id
LEFT JOIN ON city lawyer.city_id = city.id
LEFT JOIN district lawyer.district_id ON = district.id
WHERE STATE_NAME = "Alabama"
                AND city.name = "Birmingham"
                AND district.name = "Northern";
```

Others will appear similarly, depending on the query.

It should be acceptably fast.